# Make a mercurial archive without prefix

Tags: mercurial, archive

Maybe a a silly question, but my googles don't work. Doing the following on my repository root:

```
$ hg archive my_archive.tar.gz
```

Gives me a tar.gz file with an inner directory named `my_archive`, then inside my repo contents.

I understand this is meant by `hg arhives`'s help:

> Each member added to an archive file has a directory prefix prepended.
>
> Use  -p/--prefix to specify a format string for the prefix. The
> default is the basename of the archive, with suffixes removed.

But it boggles my deployment workflow. I need it without the inner dir.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify the prefix as the current directory:

```
hg archive -p . my_archive.tar.gz
```