# export mercurial repo to zip root (without prefix)

Tags: mercurial

When I use this command:

```
hg archive -t zip -p "" test.zip
```

it zips the file, but in a subdirectory named test.  So the files are in test.zip/test/(my_files).

I would like to export to test.zip directly, that's why I tried an empty prefix (-p ""), I also tried "." as prefix, but it always create a subdirectory.

In my particular case, I want to be able to run "python archive.zip" which requires the ____main__.py file to be directly in the zip's root; this is why I want to subdirectory.

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that docs say: "Use -p/--prefix to specify a **format string** for the prefix". That suggests to me it may not be a raw string/prefix (I've never used it before). At any rate, `-p "."` worked for me with a unix `unzip`.

Comment: Also note that [the accepted answer of a (near?) duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12204615/55504) also suggests `-p .`. Are you actually unzipping and seeing sub-dir with that? If so, how are you unzipping this that you still see a sub-directory with that? If not, is the issue just with python?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentionned that I tried -p ".", but it only created a folder ".", so my files are in file.zip/./(myfiles).  Also, I'm using Windows, but I don't get what's different in this switch usage vs. Unix.

Comment: You did mention ".", but it worked for me (not with python, just with unzip). Directory paths and filenames are very different in Windows compared to unix :( and many windows programs do "silly" things (from a unix perspective at least). The little I've found related to this suggests to me that python's support for running from a zip file may be limited/picky.

Comment: Yes and no, I mean it's really mercurial that put all the files in a subdirectory of the archive's root.  I guess Python could check if only a subdirectory is present and check in it, but I think that'd be a bit out of scope for the feature.  Anyways, right now for me it looks like a mercurial bug specifically on Windows.  I'll try to find where I can report it.  Thanks for the help!